# Can I expense a trip to a coffee shop (small business owner)

Tags: united-states, business, tax-law

I own a small business and work out of my home. Sometimes I like to work out of a coffee shop for a few hours here and there.

Can I expense the coffee that I buy at a coffee shop?

Comment: What is this use of "expense" as a verb?!?

Comment: @curiousdannii - it's a [dictionary usage](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/expense?s=t), and quite common in the U.S.

Comment: @feetwet I'm sure it is, but I don't think I've ever heard it before. It's completely unnatural in AusEng. :)

Comment: @curiousdannii - Is there an AUS equivalent?  Or are personal tax rates so low there nobody concerns themselves with "expensing" (i.e., paying for business-related things with pre-tax dollars)?

Comment: @feetwet You would use the verb deduct instead "Can I deduct a trip to a coffee shop?"

Comment: @curiousdannii - That's also frequently used here, probably more than "expense."  And, I think, makes more sense.

Comment: @feetwet - in the US, using 'expense' as a verb is common when referring to the action of being reimbursed by your company for an expense you took. So the individual 'expenses' it to the company and the company then 'deducts' it from their revenue as a business expense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For U.S. companies and proprietors: **No**.  In general you can only deduct food costs for necessary business travel, and then it is subject to either published "per diem" rates or a "50% limit".

Start your adventure [reading at the IRS, Publication 463, here](http://www.irs.gov/publications/p463/ch02.html#en_US_2014_publink100033862)!

Amusingly, if you have a separate office, [you *can* fully deduct the cost of "refreshments" (which includes coffee) in that office](http://blogs.findlaw.com/free_enterprise/2012/01/how-to-deduct-coffee-donuts-as-biz-expenses.html) as a "business supply."

Comment: Can you expense an employee's coffee at the shop?

Comment: @Viktor - Yes, if you are having a "business meeting" there.  Same linked section of Pub 463 covers that scenario.

Answer (score 2):

In Australia, you can claim the GST and a tax deduction for coffee you buy for clients, suppliers, etc. but not for owners or employees. They must either pay for it themselves or, if the company does, it is not tax deductible. Alternatively, it can be treated as a fringe benefit; fringe benefits over $100 per year per employee must have fringe benefits tax paid and are then deductible for GST and income tax.

In addition, if the employee (owner) is staying away from home overnight; they may claim meal (and accommodation, transport etc.) either at cost (subject to limits that increase with your base salary) or on a *per diem* rate set by the ATO based on the location.