# Small Business - Can I expense small gifts to myself as a reward (i.e. gift card)

Tags: tax-law

I recently asked if I could [expense Starbucks trips that I make to buy myself a coffee](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/4599/can-i-expense-a-trip-to-a-coffee-shop-small-business-owner). This has become frequent due to the long hours I'm putting in.

Since I cannot expense coffee trips that I take by myself, can I have my business buy *me* a Starbucks gift card as a reward for the long hours I'm putting in, and have it expensed? Can I also do this for future employees?

*Business type: Single Member LLC*

Comment: I'm not a CPA, but you can check this IRS [publication](https://www.irs.gov/publications/p463/ch03.html) out.  However, it's often said that there are certain deductions that raise the likelihood of getting an audit...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The IRS rules on deductibility of business gifts are in [Pub 463](https://www.irs.gov/publications/p463/ch03.html).  Deductibility of business gifts "for the eventual personal use or benefit of a particular person or a limited class of people" is limited to $25 per person per year.

[Furthermore](http://www.nolo.com/legal-encyclopedia/question-deduct-employee-gift-cost-28066.html),

> Cash – or cash equivalents, such as gift certificates – are looked
>   at differently through the tax authorities' eyes.... You must
>   treat such gifts as additional compensation, no matter what the
>   amount. These gifts are subject to withholding.

I wouldn't be surprised if there were a restriction on giving gifts to yourself, but since you're talking about a maximum tax benefit of single-digit dollars per year I don't consider it likely to make a material difference whether you claim it or not.